# what else to enable to make LOAD DATA INFILE work?

Tags: mysql, load

Anyone got an idea what to enable to make the `LOAD DATA INFILE` working? I have the global variable 'local_infile' set to ON, the database is answering queries just normaly, but `LOAD DATA INFILE` results in the error:

> Access denied for user 'xyxyxyx'@'%' (using password: YES)

Comment: I swear I went through at least 50 similar sites. The answer may also be that I just don't have enough rights to do LOAD DATA INFILE. But before I ask DB admin, I want to check whether the fault is on my side.

Comment: You may also need the LOCAL keyword:  `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...`.  And check for permissions to access the directory where the file is.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, to use LOAD DATA INFILE on server files, you must have the FILE
>   privilege.

-[MySQL Manual for LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)

For generic connection error troubleshooting, go [to the corresponding manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-connecting.html).

Comment: jynus, you might have also mentioned google.com as a reource to look for answers :-)

Comment: I just checked, my username has all privileges granted. Regarding the bad search skills, I think it would be nice to have some patience with newbies...