# MySQL workbench won't import my sql file

Tags: mysql-workbench, password

I have an SQL file im trying to import via mysqlworkbench but I keep getting the error:

```
Access denied for user 'wordpressuser79'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Operation failed with exitcode 1
```

All other migrations have worked out just fine, problem seems to be that its not using the password but I cannot find anywhere to fill this in. All other connections I made in mysqlworkbench have worked fine and imported SQL files as it should but somehow this one refuses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/97124/30545

Comment: Did you create a MySQL Connection from the home screen for user 'wordpressuser79', confirm that it works (Test Connection), and use said connection for this import?